# What is name of this control?

Tags: windows-controls

What is this control in picture in C# .Net? As I remember It was used in Windows XP environment however I don't know the name of this control.

[image: C# control sample]

Comment: Looks like a ListView in an expander. I don't recall if there's a win32 common expander control though.

Comment: If it is WPF you can use a spy tool like https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ to spy into the control. No idea if there is smth similar for forms.The spy tool displays the visual tree.

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Comment: C# does not have any controls. Winforms and WPF have controls.

Comment: @Will I disagree.  I think you're suggesting that this is asking for 3rd party tools/etc, which is off-topic.  However, the OP is asking 'what is this thing' and doesn't know if it's 3rd party or not.  If you'd like to offer an answer that it doesn't exist in .net 4.6 (or something), that's fine.  but it's not off-topic because the OP isn't asking for library suggestions.

Comment: @Keith Wrongly. Been off topic for a long time. https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/29/lets-play-the-guessing-game/ related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203880/what-is-the-appropriate-preferred-method-for-questions-concerning-programming and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222239/are-guessing-game-questions-off-topic and probably more on [meta].

Comment: ok, so there are meta's about it.  but the help center link gives no mention of 'guessing games'.  I'd say the burden is on SO to update their definition of off-topic in the help center rather than pretend like every user will read through the entire blog and meta site.

Comment: @Keith Thanks for your comment and declaration. But where does newbie should look for solving this sort of 'guessing games'?

Comment: @VSB I'm not sure there's a good answer for you.  I understand that it's not really what SO is wanting to be known for, but crowdsourcing these answers makes sense, so it seems to be a reasonable use of SO IMHO.  I knew SO's statement of 3rd party library searches being off-topic, but this one was news to me.  Sorry, I can't say I really support SO's decision, but I suppose we should respect it?  Wish I had somewhere to send you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember it was a TaskPane and a ListView inside.

The GotDotNet Web site disappeared by Summer 2007. [VB Helper](https://www.vb-helper.com/tip_gotdotnet_powerpack.html) contains an archive of the Visual Basic Power Pack.

The Power Pack includes seven controls written in Visual Basic 2003. They (or at least their code) may still be useful in your version of Visual Basic, although some newer features in Visual Basic or the .NET Framework may supersede them.

- BlendPanel - Provides a background with linear gradient shading.
- UtilityToolbar 
  A toolbar that has a look and feel similar to the Microsoft Internet Explorer toolbar.
- ImageButton 
  A button with a transparent background.
- NotificationWindow 
  Displays text and graphics in a popup notification window.
- TaskPane 
  A container that provides collapsible panes similar to the WPF Expander control.
- FolderViewer 
  Displays a hierarchical view of a directory tree.
- FileViewer 
  Displays a list of the files in a directory.

So you may want to use the components dll.

[image]